# Why does my values from matlab GUi failed to be inserted into database?

Tags: sql, matlab, sql-insert, matlab-guide

I have 3 edit texts in matlab which gets user input. I've managed to get the values in array when I run *disp (data);*. How do I insert my text1,text2 and text3 into my database columns named value1, value2 and value3 respectively using *fastinsert*?

```html
text1 = get(handles.edit0,'String'); 
text2 = get(handles.edit1,'String');
text3 = get(handles.edit2,'String');



tablename = 'description';
data = {text1,text2,text3};
colnames = {'value1','value2','value3'};
disp (data);
fastinsert(conn,tablename,colnames,data);

commit(conn);
```

Comment: Why do you store data in a cell array? Try data = [text1,text2,text3]

Comment: what does not work with your code?

Comment: @Benoit_11..erm..not sure..i get to display all the values in my command window..but nothing is entering the database..all I get is 'Error using database/fastinsert '